# How to check logs of nexjs project deployed in google app engine standard environment?

Tags: reactjs, django, google-app-engine, next.js

I have created nextjs project with [Isomorphic admin theme](https://themeforest.net/item/isomorphic-react-redux-admin-dashboard/20262330)

Now I am going to deploy this project to google app engine.
I read this [discussion](https://github.com/bradrisse/nextjs-9-gae-demo) and structured my app based on this [repo](https://github.com/bradrisse/nextjs-9-gae-demo)

This is my app.yaml

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs14
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

and my package.json file

```
... ...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 3030",
    "start": "next start",
    "serve": "next start",
    "build": "rimraf build && next build",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy --project [Project-ID]",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=1 next build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  }
... ...
```

I added build dir and deployed to google app engine,but it shows 500 error.

1. Where can i check server error log?
   I guess that nodejs server didn't start correctly, but no way to check error message.
2. Should I use cloud-build and build-triggers to automate deployment on github commit?
   What is the best approach to deploy nextjs project to app engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view your logs in Production,

1. Login to Google Cloud Console i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Click the hamburger menu icon (the 3 short horizontal rows) and in the drop down, look for Operations and under it `Logging`
3. Select `legacy log viewer`

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you please check this post and let me know your suggestions?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215588/why-couldnt-nodejs-instance-start-successfully-in-google-app-engine-standard-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215588/why-couldnt-nodejs-instance-start-successfully-in-google-app-engine-standard-en)

Comment: I will check on this later in the day and will provide a response on that question directly

Comment: package.json in this post is different from package.json in the other post. Secondly, how are you trying to deploy your app. Looking at the package.json here, it expects you to run ```next deploy``` which will then trigger ```gcloud app deploy``` after doing some prework. Is this what you are doing? Were you instead directly running ```gcloud app deploy```? Maybe you should post the output of the log you get from Google Cloud console

Comment: My current package.json is in second post. I am deploying by running command in gcloud sdk directly, not running "npm run deploy".


`gcloud app deploy --project [project-id]`

I found server log according to your answer and posted log message on second post. It shows 
`The request failed because the instance could not start successfully`
Do you mean any other log refering Cloud console log?