# Why couldn't nodejs instance start successfully in google app engine standard environment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, next.js

I am deploying nextjs project to goole app engine standard environment.

I got some inspiration from this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12474) and structured my app based on this [repo](https://github.com/bradrisse/nextjs-9-gae-demo).

(I tried to deploy this demo project to my app engine and confirmed it's working well)

However app engine shows 500 error after I deploy my project.

https://stars-website-nextjs.ue.r.appspot.com/

As I check the app engine log, it shows this message.

> The request failed because the instance could not start successfully

This is my app.yaml

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs14
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

and my package.json file

```
... ...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 3030",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
    "serve": "next start -p 8080",
    "gcp-predeploy": "find ./build -name '\\[...*' -exec bash -c 'mv \"$1\" \"${1/.../@@@}\"' -- {} \\;",
    "gcp-build": "find ./build -name '\\[@@@*' -exec bash -c 'mv \"$1\" \"${1/@@@/...}\"' -- {} \\;",
    "build": "rm -rf ./build && next build",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run gcp-predeploy && gcloud app deploy",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
... ...
```

My understanding is that if I upload nextjs build dir to app engine, it will automatically run the "start" command in package.json.

I deployed same project to vercel.com and it's working well https://stars-nextjs.vercel.app.

Why doesn't google app engine start my project successfully?

Can I check nodejs instance logs somewhere?

I am quite novice to app engine, so I am open to any other approachs for deploying nextjs project to app engine.
I also read about cloud build and build-trigger for automatic build and deploy and it sounds fasinating, but not sure where to get started.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you did it already, but you need to enable the App Engine API for your project first, setup required IAM permission for a service account that will run your deployment and trigger the project build on gcloud CLoud Shell.

check this guide about [Deploying to App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#yaml)

and this one to double check the parameters included in your yaml and json files for your build configuration.
[Build configuration overview](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config#yaml).

Comment: Thanks for reaching me out! As for now, I would like to find out why server didn't start successfully. 
As you can see in my post, I confirmed demo project [nextjs-9-gae-demo](https://github.com/bradrisse/nextjs-9-gae-demo) running on app engine, and followed same approach to deploy my project.

Comment: From your comment in your other post, you are running ```gcloud app deploy```directly. try running ```npm deploy``` as stated in your package.json script and see if it solves your problem. That command first does a build before doing the upload. Maybe the issue is that you don't have a build or it is corrupted so doing this might fix it.

Comment: I am pretty sure I uploaded correct build dir. As stated above, I successfully published my repository to vercel.com. I build on local and confirme it's working before uploading.
Eventhough I built successfully on local, I admit that build folder might has some issue since nodejs server couldn't start in app engine. 
But I need to check specific log for this nodejs server.
Maybe things like "module not found" which we commonly see on local development server.
The useful infomation I can get form gae server log is that The request failed because the instance could not start successfully

Answer (score 0):

When your application is returning 500 errors, make sure to look at the stdout and stderr logs of your application in Stackdriver Logging at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer. Double check that you are looking at "GAE Application" resource picker.

I also replicated your issue, used the same package.json and app.yaml file you were using and cloned the Git Hub repo files you said you used to structure your application. I am giving a detailed description of what steps I took after the initial setup:

**npm update**

**npm i**

{To update the packages listed to the latest version)

Note : Also keep in mind that your package.json and package-lock.json should be in sync with the packages

I opened cloud console  and enabled the following API :

1. App Engine API
2. Compute Engine API
3. Cloud Build API

Also I granted these roles to my service account : App Engine Admin, Cloud Build Service account.

App Engine Admin role : Full management of app engine apps and not storage.

Cloud Build Service Account : Can perform builds.

Then I opened a new terminal in VSCode and ran the following commands:

1. **npm run dev**
2. **gcloud auth login**

This command took me to a sign in page where I logged in to the above mentioned service account. I gave allow permissions to Google Cloud SDK.

3. **gcloud init**

[i]Reinitialised existing configuration

[ii]Chose my service account

[iii]Chose project-id

[iv]Chose us-central for the region where my app would be deployed.

4. **npm run build**
5. **npm run deploy**
6. **gcloud app browse**

The issue seems to be happening on your end  because you are using ‘gcloud app deploy’. Try running npm run build and then npm run deploy as stated in your package.json script and see if it solves your problem. That command first does a build before doing the actual upload. Also enable all the APIs I listed and grant the roles to your cloud build service account. If the problem still persists, let me know.